# Crystal Reports for VS2010 Constantly Asking to Upgrade Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 installed. When I work on our old projects, it asks if I would like to upgrade Crystal Reports. I don't want to upgrade Crystal Reports on our old projects, ever. How do I get the window to not open? I am completely OK with breaking the upgrade feature 100% if that is what is required.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlqhu.png

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3357639) from SAP. Apparently there is an issue if you have runtimes from older versions installed.

Comment: I ended up having to format for an unrelated problem. After the format the issue with Crystal Reports no longer occurred.